# linking activitys on gridview, android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gridview

I have an problem by linking activitys in an gridview.

My code is here:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context mContext;

    public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    public int getCount() {
        return mThumbIds.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    // create a new ImageView for each item referenced by the Adapter
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {  // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
            imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            imageView.setBackgroundColor(0);
            imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
        }
        imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
        if(position == 2)
        {
           Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News.class);
           startActivity(nextScreen);   
        }
        if(position == 1)
        {
           Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Open.class);
           startActivity(nextScreen);   

        }

        return imageView;

    }

    // references to our images
    private Integer[] mThumbIds = {
            R.drawable.info, R.drawable.open,
            R.drawable.news, R.drawable.specials,
            R.drawable.maerkte, R.drawable.anfahrt,
            R.drawable.artikel, R.drawable.kontakt,

    };

}
```

I think ists only a small problem :( I´m searching since few days to get an answer,..  :(
I hope you can help me and I would thank you before I get the right answer ;)

Have a nice day

Comment: This kind of code works better in your `onItemClickListener`, can you not put it there? Outside the adapter, in your fragment/activity where the gridview is.

Comment: did you have an example how I can realize that?

Comment: I've posted an answer - hope it makes sense. `getView()` is not the best place for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the code in your `onItemClickListener()`, not in `getView()`

Something like:

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        if (pos == 2) {
           Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), News.class);
           startActivity(nextScreen);   
        }
        else if (pos == 1) {
           Intent nextScreen = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Open.class);
           startActivity(nextScreen);   
        }
    }
});
```

This code will be in your Activity/Fragment/wherever you have the gridView, not inside your custom adapter.